# Why is adding a comment inappropriate?

Tags: bug, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

I was asked to review [this answer](https://serverfault.com/review/first-posts/141441). I added a comment about how it could have been more helpful. And was then told, it was an inappropriate review.

Why is adding a comment considered to be inappropriate?

Comment: From what I understand review audits are funky things ...unless it's an absolutely horrible answer, the audit just expects you to say "it looks okay".

Comment: Well your comment is correct enough, but not sure why the review was brought up on that answer from Basil at all in the queue.

Answer (score 6):

You got a Review Audit. On those, if the original edit was approved then you can only "pass" the audit by also clicking "looks okay". If you click anything else, including leaving a comment, you fail. It's dumb, but failing makes no difference unless you fail a lot...

This seems to happen once every few months, you're not alone.

Answer (score 4):

Breaking it down:

- Comments are a neutral concept.
- Badges for review tasks are dumb and encourage people to do dumb things things.
- The devs need the comment action to trigger a pass or fail, because Review Audits are more focused on catching you "gaming the system" than teaching good behavior.
- Review Audits are dumb.